# Using getNamedItem function in DOM

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript

Am trying to use the function getNamedItem in xml DOM through Vb script but it never works. Below is the piece of code and XMl document.
Please help me in finding out the error, thanks in advance.

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmldom")
obj.async = false
obj.load ("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\Parsing XML\Books.xml")
Set root = obj.documentElement
Set child = root.childNodes
Set Node = child.item(1)
s=Node.getNamedItem('author')
Msgbox s
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: here is the xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title> 
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> 
<year>2005</year> 
<price>30.00</price> 
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title> 
<author>J K. Rowling</author> 
<year>2005</year> 
<price>29.99</price> 
</book>
</bookstore>

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quotes:

```
getNamedItem('author') - use double quotes "
```

Wrong function:

```
getNamedItem - Returns IXMLDOMNode object for the specified attribute.
```

Something like:

```
 Dim root  : Set root  = objMSXML.documentElement
 Dim child : Set child = root.childNodes
 Dim Node  : Set Node = child.item(1)
 Dim ndFnd : Set ndFnd = Node.selectSingleNode("author")
 WScript.Echo ndFnd.text
```

will give you:

```
J K. Rowling
```

Sample use of getNamedItem():

```
...     
Dim Node  : Set Node = child.item(1)
WScript.Echo Node.attributes.getNamedItem("category").value
```

Comment: Thank you, one question what does IXMLDOMNode means?

Comment: @user1925406 - 'IXMLDOMNode' is the class/type name of the object(s) returned by `getNamedItem()`.