# Open a XML with ASP

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

I am trying to read a XML File with ASP (absolute beginner in ASP).

The XML to open:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reisen>
  <Reise Reise-Nummer="5608" Status="Released">
    <Pfad>Reisen/Europa/DE/Bayerischer_Wald/5608</Pfad>
    <Informationen>
<Anforderung>1-2</Anforderung>
    </Informationen>
    <Reisedaten>
<Titel>Eine Reise durch den Bayrischen Wald</Titel>
    </Reisedaten>
  </Reise>
</Reisen>
```

The ASP code:
(file_name contains the file name of the xml)

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")    
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("/xml/single/" & file_name)


Dim xmlProduct  
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Reisen")
     Dim reise : reise = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("Reise").Attributes.GetNamedItem("Reise-Nummer").Text  
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(reise)  
Next
```

If I call this script, I always get an error 500. The error is placed in the foreach-loop...
Can someone show me how to fix it?

Comment: Hey @Lankymart,
unfortunately, that´s not the solution. :(
getting the error anyway...

Comment: @Lankymart - your speculations are just that, cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/12/07/277763.aspx. Moving the `Dim` won't fix anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14966778/603855 and check whether `.Text` should be `.value`.

Comment: Hey Ekkehard.Horner, thank you for your advice.
unfortunately, the error 500 is still there

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for the correction. You can't be right all the time it was a guess plain and simple based on a 30 second glimpse at the code. I don't tend to declare inside loops but knowing it doesn't break is useful. Excellent article as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is Reisen is the root node with multiple child Reise nodes inside. In that case you shouldn't use selectNodes for Reisen. I tested the following and seems to be working fine:

```
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("/xml/single/" & file_name)

Set root = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("/Reisen")

Dim xmlProduct 
For Each xmlProduct In root.selectNodes("./Reise")
     Dim reise : reise = xmlProduct.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Reise-Nummer").Text  
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(reise)  
Next
```

I tried with multiple Reisen elements with no root and I got HTTP 500 so it might be the case that your XML is not valid after all which is causing the error.

Comment: Hey Volkan,
now i am getting the error 500 at line 6 (set root...) and in the for each loop

Comment: Could you make sure it's actually loading the file. For example replace everything under objXMLDoc.load with Response.Write objXMLDoc.documentElement.nodeName. It should return Reisen

Comment: holy... thanks a lot... the first "/" wasn´t needed/wrong... -.-
thanks a lot!